# Box Move owned files API is synchronous call

Tags: box

Box move owned files api call is synchronous (https://api.box.com/2.0/users/user_id/folders/folder_id). If the user has large number of files then it will take hours sometimes.  we are planning it to implement such a way that make the call and timeout. then periodically check the number of items in root folder of the user, if it is empty, then assume that transfer is done. can we rely on this approach?

Another question is that if a file or folder is shared with user, will move owned items api call have any effect on the shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

This approach does not work if user has shared files/folders. Move owned items call does not move unowned items. Hence this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using some asynchronous framework like NodeJS, where it can upload multiple files simultaneously upto your enterprise set connection limit. https://github.com/box/box-node-sdk